# MYSQL "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table" when attempting to find user

Tags: php, mysql

When I attempt to run the following query from php, I get no result (even though there is a user that matches the info given.

```
SELECT * FROM `virtual_users` WHERE `email`='$u', `password` = ENCRYPT('".$p."', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

In another script the following query works fine:

```
"UPDATE `virtual_users` SET `password`=ENCRYPT('".$sNewPassword."', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))) WHERE `email`='". $oAccount->Email () ."'"
```

After sitting there stumped for a while, I attempted to run the query using explain from within PHP my Admin:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `virtual_users` WHERE `email`='fakeuser@fake.fake' AND `password` = ENCRYPT('fakepass', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

Which returned the following

> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
>   | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
>   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
>   | 1 | SIMPLE | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
>   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

The table structure is as follows:
[Table Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpGN1.png)

Any help would be greatly apreciated.
Signed,
Mike

Comment: Apart from the syntax woe in your SELECT, how is it supposed to match with feeding a fresh `RAND()` on each run?

Comment: I was thinking that before, you see on my vps I have apache and a mailserver (postfix and dovecot) and what I'm actually attempting to do is settup another system which uses the same acounts. I was trying to update the password change query to a login check for the other bit.

Comment: If postfix/dovecot uses a *crypt(1)* password, then better just fetch it, and check with `password_verify` in PHP. Better yet create it with `password_hash()` as well. Most system libs understand newer hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mario solved it.
Basically I changed the script from accessing the database and looking up the password to instead get the password from the database and use password verify to check it like so:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `virtual_users` WHERE `email`='$u'";
        <snip>
                $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
                if(password_verify($_POST['pass'], $row['password'])){
        <snip>
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` does not use a comma.  I believe the syntax you want is `AND`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `virtual_users`
WHERE `email` = '$u' AND `password` = ENCRYPT('".$p."', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

Comment: Thanks changed that although it didn't fix the overeaching problem, which it apears mario stumbled onto.

Comment: They probably thought they could use the same syntax from their UPDATE code. That would explain the comma they used.